# Testflight isn't recognizing new devices

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning, testflight

I'm trying to add a user to a Testflight build. So I go to the Developer Portal and add their info (UDID and Device name) and add their device to the provisioning profile, redownload it, and apply it to the project. Then I archive to an .ipa file. However, when I upload the ipa to Testflight, I'm only seeing the users that were available before, I would exact the new ID to show up under "Anonymous" or something. I opened up the .ipa file (convert to zip, unzip, check Payload/embeddedprofile.mobileprovision) and the device's UDID that I added was there, so it's just Testflight refusing to add my device. Is there something up with the Testflight service, or am I missing something? I'm not getting any errors at any step, just not seeing the new UDID in the "Invite Testers" page (and the user can't access the build, Testflight turns them away).

-Esa

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you didn't apply it when you archived the project for distribution. I did the same thing, took me an hour or so to figure that out! You need to double check that your Ad Hoc profile is selected in this dialog.

[image]

Comment: Didn't apply what? The Provisioning profile? I opened up the ipa and the correct devices were there in the embedded file, but Testflight wasn't recognizing them. I am using the correct profile for certain.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my account completely and started over with a new email address and it works now.

Comment: Are you using two accounts --- Stack Overflow accounts?

Comment: I had a similar problem and wound up switching to another service.  See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023757/