# Can't Install xCode 4.3 beta apps using TestFlight

Tags: xcode4.3, testflight

I just upgraded to xCode 4.3 and used it to generate a new revision of an iPad app about 50 beta testers have been using for several months. I distributed the beta app through TestFlight as usual.

Most testers upgraded with no problem, but several testers are getting the TestFlight message "You have not permitted this device to install this build" when they try to install the new rev. I've never seen this message before. Their iPad UDID is definitely in the build's embedded.mobileprovision file and everything was working working fine with the prior revision.

What am I -- or the testers -- doing wrong and how do we correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Hi i experienced the same and it seems that you must generate your mobile provisioner profile from Xcode(instead of Apple dev site for example) and you should update your App permissions (TestFlight) with this same provisioner profile that you just generated on your machine so basically the machine that generates and archive the apps using Xcode must generate the provisioner profile and then you should update your testflight app permissions with this file.

Does that make any sense?

Hope this works for you testflight is really nice to use, i faced same problems with all of my apps and hardware devices (testers all around the world)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is apparently a bug in Testflight.  I tried to resolve the issue through their support forum and multiple emails with no real answer.  I did not want to switch services as my testers knew the Testflight system well.  But eventually switched to [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com).  My testers were able to install the app using Diawi with no problems.