# TestFlight users asked to install app multiple times

Tags: testflight

Here's what's happening when my iPad beta testers are installing a new revision using Testflight. They...

1. Delete the current version of their iPad app.
2. Install the new revision of the app on their iPad from the TestFlight email.
3. Open the app.

A Testflight screen then appears saying there is a new version of the app and asking if they would like to install it. If the user reinstalls the app, the same screen reappears when they open the app.

They've already installed the new version. Is this a Testflight bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at [Can't Install xCode 4.3 beta apps using TestFlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023757/) for a related issue that was solved by switching services.