# Testflight isn't recognizing new devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Hello friends i made an ipa by using a provisioning profile which includes four UDID but when i uploded this ipa on testflight it shows only two UDID which it shows before.

I have visited [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195933/testflight-isnt-recognizing-new-devices) as well but got no clue.

Sorry i am not very good in English language.

I used provisioning profile whose screenshot is added below.
[image]

Comment: have you checked whether new UDID's are shown on the organiser window of xcode

Comment: George i have seen that All UDID are there in embedded.mobileprovision in payload but testflight is not showing these attached devices in anonymous devices section.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201934)

Their said you can manually upload provisioning profile by going to

TestFlight >> builds >> Permissions >> Upload profile

Hopes this will help you